# Can't post from Unity to Facebook feed properly

Tags: unity, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK for Unity.
I'm posting to the user's feed with the Feed function.

According to Facebook, I do not need any permission for it.

"Sharing stories via Feed Dialog does not require any extended permissions, and a person can easily change the audience for each story they choose to share."
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2

```
1) FB.Init(OnInitComplete);

2) FB.Login("", OnLoginComplete);

3) FB.Feed(link: LinkToApp,
           linkName: LinkName,
           linkCaption: LinkCaption,
           callback: OnPublishLinkComplete);
```

When I log in with a user which is not an admin this is the process:

1) the application is asking permission for my public profile - I click ok

2) A popup of sharing comes up, I type in my text and click Post

3) Gets me back to the app but not posting happened

4) Trying to post again

5) A popup of "Oops, Something Went Wrong" comes op

Then the process repeats itself from 2 to 5.

---------- Update ----------

If I use the 6.2.1 version, I get "Oops, Something Went Wrong".
If I use the 6.0 version, the post gets shared, but the callback returns with {"cancelled":true}.

Comment: You clearly need permission for it, as your first step is asking for permission. When you then apparently throw away `FB.Login(""`?

Comment: Maybe you should link the documentation about Facebook saying you don't need permission to post something on a user's feed.

Comment: I added the quote from the documentation. I could write FB.Login("email") or other stuff but I don't need any extended permissions. By default it asks the public profile info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in their SDK for Unity:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598200610227965/

There is a workaround, you can change the DialogMode in the FbUnityInterface.mm

From this

```
self.dialogMode = NativeDialogModes::FAST_APP_SWITCH_SHARE_DIALOG;
```

To this

```
self.dialogMode = NativeDialogModes::WEBVIEW_DIALOG_MODE;
```